# Custom Post Type “property” (wp-property plugin) query issues

Tags: wordpress

I've got wp-property plugin installed, and I am trying to have a custom query, to retrieve data from the database.

If I query posts from other post_type is ok, but when I try to query posts from the specific "property "post_type, generated by the plugin, it only shows me one ID or one title (see picture attached to understand...
[image]
Here is my code, I tried with normal wp-query structure, but I got the same problem:

```
    <?php
    $querystr = "
    SELECT *
    FROM `wp_posts`
    WHERE `post_type` LIKE 'property'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
    ";

    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

    ?>
    <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
    <?php global $post; ?>
    <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <?php echo  $post->post_title ?><br />

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a conflict between the global `$post` variable and your loop variable.  Does it work if you change it to the following (untested) code?

```
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php foreach ($pageposts as $pagepost): ?>
<?php setup_postdata($pagepost); ?>
<?php echo  $post->post_title ?><br />
```

By the way your SQL is missing some conditions - you'll pull back all revisions of your posts with that.  At the very least I'd add

```
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

but I'd go back to using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if at all possible.

Comment: Hi Hobo, i tried with WP_Query, but it isn't working. Just I cant understand, should be a very simple query, but it doesn't work. I did try with your code, but it doesn't works. I think the problem is with the wp-property plugin.